# Can I scale a shape in box2d as sprite do?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, scale

As we always use the function in cocos2d,I can scale my sprite whenever I want.Can I do the same thing in box2d?For example, I created a circle shaped body,then I want to make it bigger.

I tried reassign the m_radius after I created a circle,but not work.

Comment: http://www.box2d.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=5601&p=26070#p26070 check out this.. you will find that one person able to do it by changing the radius...Hope this may help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are simply assigning shape.m_radius to a new value, it will not work.

You need to reference the shape object associated with the b2Fixture that you created for your object:

```
fixture->GetShape()->m_radius = new_radius/PTM_RATIO;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: To get the mass characteristics to match the new size you would also need a ResetMassData for the body. A more reliable and future-proof method is to destroy and recreate the fixture (although this can be a nuisance if you have game logic associated with it).

Comment: Thanks buddy,It works.I found where the problem is.If I type circle.m_radius = radius/PTM_RATIO,it just assign the variable of an object that I'll never use.I must get the shape from the fixture then reassign it as you suggested.