# How can I change the size of a body in box2d?

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

How can I change the size of a body in box2d with andengine? There is no methods to do that in the body class. Is there another class that will do that?

Comment: check out this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075359/can-i-scale-a-shape-in-box2d-as-sprite-do

hope this will work for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can't so what I ended up having to do is destroy the body then make a new one.