# Cocos2d change box2d shape radius dynamically

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, sprite, shapes

Can I change box2d radius on tap? This is code

```
b2BodyDef ballBodyDef;
ballBodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
ballBodyDef.position.Set(pos.x / PTM_RATIO, pos.y / PTM_RATIO);
ballBodyDef.userData = mainBallon;
_bodyMain = _world->CreateBody(&ballBodyDef);

circleMain.m_radius = circleRadius / PTM_RATIO;

ballShapeDefMain.shape = &circleMain;
ballShapeDefMain.density = 1.0f;
ballShapeDefMain.friction = 0.2f;
ballShapeDefMain.restitution = 0.8f;
_bodyMain->CreateFixture(&ballShapeDefMain);
```

I want to  increase radius in this method.

```
-(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

I tried this:

```
circleMain.m_radius = NewRadius;
_bodyMain->ResetMassData();
```

and this:

```
b2Fixture *fixtureA = _bodyMain->GetFixtureList();
_bodyMain->DestroyFixture(fixtureA);

b2CircleShape circleShape;
circleShape.m_radius = NewRadius;

b2FixtureDef fixtureDef;
fixtureDef.shape = &circleShape;
fixtureDef.density = 1;
fixtureDef.friction = 0.2f;
fixtureDef.restitution = 0.8f;
_bodyMain->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);
```

but both wont work.

Comment: The 2nd part, removing the old shape and adding a new one, is the only way to make this work. Perhaps you needn't remove the entire fixture, just the shape itself?

Comment: I found this, it's working. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075359/can-i-scale-a-shape-in-box2d-as-sprite-do